# Python (sobrescrição)

Tags: python

Tem como eu sobrescrever o conteúdo de um print sem ser manualmente, após um time.sleep()? Ex.:

```
print('Me ajudem!') #Texto "inicial"
time.sleep(3600) #Após um minuto, o texto inicial some e no lugar aparece:
print('Fui salvo!)
```

Comment: Olá, vais ter sempre de dizer de alguma maneira o que queres como output (conteúdo do print neste caso), ou queres que o computador adivinhe o que queres mostrar?

Comment: Por que você não limpa o console antes de dar um output?